# nuget - package restore not working

Tags: nuget

My aim is to have package restore working on a build server so that I don't have to check in binaries. At the moment, I'm simply trying to get it to work on my own machine using Visual Studio.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Followed the instructions here http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages, including both setting the Tools-Options flag and the environment variable (belt and braces)
2. Installed the NuGetEnablePackageRestore package as suggested here [NuGet package restore consent without NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828115/nuget-package-restore-consent-without-nuget)
3. Checked everything in (the .nuget solution folder and its contents), but not the binaries I want to reference, because that's the whole point of the exercise

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Check out solution
2. Verify that nunit.framework.dll and moq.dll are not present in the checked out solution
3. Build the solution

Visual Studio complains that Moq is missing. I search for the dlls in the solution directory and find that:

1. nunit.framework.dll is present in the appropriate bin folders
2. Moq.dll is nowhere to be found

But there's more. This is truly mysterious, but if I do a fresh checkout, disconnect from the internet and build, I get precisely the same results - nunit.framework.dll is there, but moq.dll is not. **The build process has conjured nunit.framework.dll literally from nowhere.**

So it's something of an understatement to say that I am completely baffled. Can anyone suggest answers to the following questions:

1. Why is package restore not downloading Moq?
2. Where on earth is the build process getting nunit.framework.dll, if not the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I noticed in the documentation that enabling package restore was supposed to modify project files in order to add a new target. My project files did not have this change. Right-clicking the solution title in VS and selecting 'Manage NuGet packages...' then added the required changes and everything built as it should.

I checked, and package restore still appears to work when I have no internet access, so I'm still mystified about that. Does NuGet maintain some kind of cache of binaries outside the solution?

Comment: Nuget does indeed keep a global cache. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders

Answer (score 2):

In vs, Options, Package Manager... there's a section "Package Cache", if you click on the "Browse" button it will take you to the location of the nuget cache in your machine.

Comment: Thank you. That has really helped to clarify things for me.

Comment: Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General -> Browse. Or Tools ->NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> General -> Browse.